# How to prevent Xcode 3.2.5 to not show those blue message bubbles when debugging?

Tags: xcode

Every time I set a breakpoint, Xcode 3.2.5 throws in a big blue message bubble taking up two lines of code and disrupting my code structure. It is so annoying. I always have to click on the breakpoint and choose "Hide message bubble".

Is this a bug or can I do a preference somewhere to avoid them?

Yes I know there is Xcode 4. I want to use Xcode 3.2.5 for this project I am working on.

Comment: I was curious with this, but couldn't replicate your behaviour - I could show and hide the message bubbles, but they weren't visible every time a breakpoint was set (by default); they were hidden when breakpoints deleted.  I see no preference for this either?  Have you tried hiding the message bubbles, saving and opening the project?  It might be a bug? Is there any reason you could try Xcode 3.2.6?

Comment: Strange. Thanks. I'll get Xcode 3.2.6 maybe it works better :=)

Comment: Yeh, it's another 4Gb download though! Update if this problem goes away?

Comment: Yes. I have a slow connection so I will wait when I can afford it. Right now I need my internet energy for something else :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, just open the Debugger window by pressing Command+Shift+Y.

Right click anywhere in the code window and go to Message Bubbles > Hide Breakpoints.

Image is attached. :)

[image: Xcode Breakpoint Message Bubbles]